# using a variable in two different java classes

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I was wondering if it's possible to use a variable of a  java class in another java class.Suppose variable Time is defined and calculated in Class A, how can I use it in Class B?

Comment: What has this got to do with JavaScript? And what have you tried? (Hint: usually you'd add a "getter" method in one class to return the value of the variable, then call the method from the other class.)

Comment: Make variable time as public or static and access it via instance of object using dot operator or ClassA.time if it is static. It's very basic question! But this is bad practice, use getters and setters. And always remeber Java != Javascript

Comment: @PradeepSimha: Those are generally *bad* suggestions. Public variables break encapsulation, and you shouldn't just arbitrarily make a variable static - you need to understand when that's suitable.

Comment: @JonSkeet, yes due to browser problem I submitted. But I have edited my comment now

Comment: @PradeepSimha: So why even suggest making it public in the first place?

Comment: @JonSkeet, don't you think there will be no scenario in world where you wouldn't use public variables? I gave him ways of doing it, if OP is asking this basic question means he is very beginner in Java.. and dumping all lots of best practices before even knowing basics is a very bad suggestion

Comment: @PradeepSimha: Very *very* rarely - and only after due consideration. The fact that the OP appears to be a beginner is all the *more* reason to be careful here: once he's got into bad habits, it'll be harder to fix them.

Comment: @JonSkeet this article by Jeff backs my point http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/properties-vs-public-variables.html :)

Comment: @PradeepSimha: Well, I vehemently disagree - would you like me to produce references which back up my viewpoint? (Jeff is simply wrong about saying "You can always refactor it later" - it's a breaking change both in binary and source terms.) See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet, I don't like to extend this discussion (different view points) but my main argument is if person doesn't even know how to access variable, first let him know you can access it via public variables, then after one or two tries he will automatically and practically come to know that public variables are bad. A good programmer should have experienced both good ways and bad ways of doing it, if he know bad ways he can better learn good ways. That's my view point

Comment: @PradeepSimha: Whereas my experience is that if you let people get into bad habits, they'll stick with them. Witness the vast swathe of questions on Stack Overflow where people are including values directly into their SQL instead of using parameterized SQL. If *only* someone had told them about parameterized SQL when they first asked how to execute a query... Your suggestion that good habits just come automatically just doesn't seem to match the reality I see every day.

Answer (score 7):

Other answers have suggested increasing a variable's visibility. **Don't** do this. It breaks encapsulation: the fact that your class uses a field to store a particular piece of information is an implementation detail; you should expose relevant information via the class's API (its methods) instead. You should make fields private in almost *all* cases.

Likewise, some other answers have suggested possibly making the variable static. **Don't** do this arbitrarily. You need to understand what static really means: it's saying that this piece of information is related to the type rather than to any one particular instance of the type. Occasionally that's appropriate, but it's generally a road towards less testable code - and in many cases it's clearly wrong. For example, a `Person` class may well have a `name` variable, but that certainly shouldn't be static - it's clearly a piece of information about a *single* person.

You should think carefully before exposing information anyway - consider whether there's a wider operation which the class in question could expose, instead of just giving away its data piecemeal - but when you *do* want to expose a field's value, use a property. For example:

```
public class Person {
    private final String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

By exposing it via a *method*, you can later change the implementation details without breaking existing clients.

Then from another class, you'd just call the `getName()` method:

```
// However you end up getting a reference to an instance of Person
Person person = ...;
String name = person.getName();
```

If you *do* have a static field, you can expose the value in the same way, but with a static method, which you'd call using the class name.

Be careful about returning values which are mutable, e.g. `java.util.Date`. This is another reason for using a getter method instead of allowing direct access to the field - you can make the method return a defensive copy where you need to.

Comment: +1 for goos explanation but what do mean with "without breaking existing clients."?

Comment: @MeNoMore: I mean that other code using the class doesn't need to change, just because you change an implementation detail, so long as you keep the same API.

Answer (score 1):

If it is declared as public, you may use `ClassA.yourVariable`. On the other hand, for private access modifier, include the getter to your `ClassA`. On the `ClassB`, call `ClassA.getYourVariable()`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Also read about [access specifiers in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) it might help.

Comment: @MeNoMore: also I am bit lazy to type all this on my own :)

Comment: Me too i'v been searching for one but couldnt find one fastly :)

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your Variable as public or static you will be able to access it from another class.

**WHICH IS A VERY VERY BAD IDEA** :)

Comment: Public and static are entirely orthogonal concerns; public variables are a bad idea anyway, and you shouldn't arbitrarily make a variable static.

Comment: @Jon Skeet your right, but the question is about "if it's possible" not if its good, so technically it is possible, i am not saying its good or makes sence but its possible.

Comment: @MeNoMore: You didn't say it was a *bad* idea either. I view this as irresponsible. The OP is clearly a beginner - why would you suggest things which are bad practice?

Comment: But, if I declare the Time variable as public static, it gives me error: illegal start of expression!!!!!!!

Comment: @JonSkeet that was'nt a suggestion too, i just wrote if hedeclares it in some way it would be accessable not more, sometimes you have to think see things from the OP Eyes, when someone is new to programming reads your answer, which is absolutely right and informativewhat do think how much would he he understands about the reasons of not using with his background?

Comment: @Mossi: At this point, I think you'd be far better served by getting hold of a good book on Java. Stack Overflow is great for fixing small problems, but it's really not good for learning a language from scratch.

Comment: @MeNoMore: Well, I think he's likely to do better with my answer than with yours... yes, it will force some *thought* and quite possibly further research - but I view that as a *much* better outcome than just a "yes, you can shoot yourself in the foot, and I'm not even going to tell you it's a bad idea" answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet Come on i didnt even wrote one "Yes" in my answer, anyway this isnt leading nowhere, allthough it could be really interessting to know how the OP sees this.

Comment: @MeNoMore: Happier - although now you're just saying what not to do, instead of giving *constructive* advice on how to achieve what the OP actually needs to do. Downvote removed as this post is no longer actively harmful.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is `static`, you can refer to it as `A.Time` from any code that has access to the variable. There's only one `Time` value for all of class A. If it is an instance variable, and you have an instance `a` of class `A`, you can refer to the variable as `a.Time`. There's a separate value for each instance of class `A`.

This is subject to Java's access rules:

- if the field is `public`, any code can access it (this makes `public` variables kind of dangerous unless they are also declared `final`)
- if the field is `protected`, only code in the same package or in a subclass of `A` can access it
- if the field has default access, only code in the same package as class A can access it
- if the field is `private`, only code in class `A` (including inner classes of `A`) can access it.

Alternatively, you can provide an *accessor method* in class A:

```
public class A {
    . . .
    public class getTime() {
        return this.Time; // the "this." is optional
    }
}
```